# order by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are my models.

```
Restaurant has many patrons
patrons have many transactions
```

In controller index all patrons like

@pts = Restaurant.find(1).patrons

and in view I simply list the patrons attributes, inluding number of transaction per patrons like

How would I order the resultset (@pts) by transaction count of each patron?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have too many patrons and you don't use a count cache (`transactions_counter`), you could do it like this:

```
@pt.sort_by{|p|p.transactions.count}.each do |patron|
...
```

Or you could set up a counter cache and do it in sql(you can do it without but the queries are a bit more annoying)

add transactions_counter to the patrons table and

```
class Patron < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, :counter_cache => true
  #...
end
```

Then you can sort by it in your query:

```
@pts = Restaurant.find(1).patrons.all :order => "patrons.transactions_counter DESC"
```

You could even add that to your has_many call and simplify things.

Answer (score -1):

This will order by id.
   Put it in the model.

```
  has_many :patrons, :order => "id DESC"
```

Comment: I am trying to order by transaction count of each patron not id. Thanks

Comment: this is not sorting patrons as requested